# Imperavi Redactor 9 removes &nbsp ; character

Tags: special-characters, redactor

How to disable the Redactor editor auto remove &nbsp ; ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix clean &nbsp;

1. open redactor.js
2. find

```js
syncClean: function(html)
{
  if (!this.opts.fullpage) html = this.cleanStripTags(html);

  html = $.trim(html);

  // removeplaceholder
  html = this.placeholderRemoveFromCode(html);

  // remove space
  html = html.replace(/&#x200b;/gi, '');
  html = html.replace(/&#8203;/gi, '');
  // html = html.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' '); // COMMENT THIS!
  ...
}
```

1. comment replacing string

profit! :)

Comment: Very bad way to modify source code - you should use [callbacks](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/) instead, like `pasteBeforeCallback` for instance.

Comment: in this situation modifying source code -- the best way (though it is bad in general). the author of redactor.js does not want to add the special setting. callbacks spoil everything (in this case).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how and what callbacks spoil?

Comment: In the callback function I must undo some changes that made ​​by the plugin. Replace all text again. Not good. One simple option would solve the problem. But this option is not available.

Comment: I agree, in general the option you're talking about would be a better solution, but in the absence of such, still wiser to resort to using callback (which would slow the execution by few microseconds, unnoticeable by user) than keep changing the code with every new script version update. Моё мнение.

Comment: Using Git/Hg/... it is not such a problem ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In new version U may set "cleanSpaces" option to "false" for disabling of `&nbsp;` auto remove.

```
$('#redactor').redactor({ cleanSpaces: false });
```

Answer (score 3):

The text and code you are seeing will be different between all the browsers and it's how contenteditable fields work. For example, some browsers insert UTF-8 characters for spaces some `&nbsp`.

RedactorJS don't gives methods to normalize the text, so you can parse the text manually. Check this:

```
var html = $('#redactor').redactor('get');
var sanitizeHtml = html.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' ').replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
```